# pymogo performance for mongodb

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I have a small confusion regarding pymongo connections . I have a situation in which I have to insert continuous stream of data into MongoDB for which I am using pymongo. The problem is once I create a connection to the DB I need to continuously insert into **different collections**? Is it good to `switch between different collections very quickly` to insert data (and this happens for very long may be for hours) . I mean will it not create any problems ? I have tried it seems to work properly but I still want to know even if I insert documents into different collections very quickly will it cause any problem?

Answer (score 0):

It won't cause any problems till your active set fits in the RAM, else you will start to see faults in `mongostat`.

The concept remains the same irrespective of your storage engine WiredTiger or MMAPv1, though you will achieve a better write and storage size performance with WiredTiger engine.

Best way to figure out long term performance is to simulate your write load, and observe [mongostat](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongostat/#fields) for that duration.